# Firebase Phone Auth "Hostname match not found" multiple sites

Tags: javascript, angular, web, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue setting up phone authentication for my website. We are developing a SaaS product which provides personal websites to each customer, on our domain under a subdomain per customer schema. Each site goes ***customer1.example.com*, *customer2.example.com*** and so on, being ***example.com*** our domain.

All of those subdomains are running under HTTPS, only solution we have for the moment it's to whitelist each single subdomain but that becomes very difficult when more clients are subscribing to our service. Firebase it's suppossed to whitelist every request coming from HTTPS but if we don't whitelist each subdomain we receive the `"Hostname match not found"` error. It's worth noting that our SSL certificates are being generated using **Let's Encrypt**, just mentioning if it's something that can be causing this issue.

Any help will be appreciated, I'm not providing code since the authentication process works both locally and on the case when we specifically whitelist the full domain.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your domain in Authentication > Sign-in methods (Scroll down) > Authorised domains